# Events do not react to extra Mousebuttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, mouseevent

I am currently developing a UI for my Unity game. Due that I have started creating a KeyBinder-Menu where one can reassign the keys. This works fine until I tryed to implement it for the Mousebuttons.

I tried using `Event.current.button` so i can handle mouse input, but first of all it returns 0 all the time when i am not pressing anything else then mousebutton 0 and secondly it does not react to my extra mousebuttons.

Then I tryed `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.MouseX)` (X would be the mousebutton I want to handle) This works fine with mousebutton 0, 1 and 2 but does not work with my extrabuttons to. I have a Mouse from Logitech with 2 extra buttons and they work fine with all games (like lol, Rainbow, minecraft ....) so I dont know why unity can not handle them.

Thanks for all answers I may get.

Comment: Have you tried using GetKey, rather than GetKeyDown? Also, for Mouse4 etc., are you sure that is how they're mapped in the system, e.g. my extra mouse buttons are actually mapped as **0** and **9**? [Try using Debug.Log with a check to get the right code](https://answers.unity.com/questions/165878/how-to-detect-which-key-is-pressed.html)

Comment: @Camile tried pretty much all of it and `GetKeyDown` just gets triggered in the frame where i push the mousebutton down but `GetKey` would give an output all the time while the button is pressed. GetKeyDown has the possibility to trigger on KeyCode values so yeah it should work. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a bug, i already submitted a bug report about it you can vote for it here:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/event-dot-button-only-supports-right-left-and-middle-mouse-buttons

However `Input.GetMouseButton(x);` will still read your extra mouse buttons correctly where x is an integer
Eg.: `Input.GetMouseButton(12);` will read your 12th mouse button on a gaming mouse ...

You can also do release, push events:

> Returns true during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.
> `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(int button);`
>
> Returns whether the given mouse button is held down or not.
> `Input.GetMouseButton(int button);`
>
> Returns true during the frame the user releases the given mouse button.
> `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(int button);`

**Update from Unity:**
*Thanks again for reporting this issue. It has been reviewed by our developers and unfortunately, it has been decided that it will not be fixed. As of now, IMGUI doesn't support more than 3 buttons, and since IMGUI is being replaced with UIElements this ability is not going to be added.*

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I have tryed what you said but first of all it does not work for me so it does not fire when i press the button and secondly it gives an error whene i use something above 5 for the button.

Comment: never mind. I found out how it works. So with `GetMouseButtonDown(int button)` it did not work but with `GetMouseButton(int button)` it did. I totally do not know why but yeah. Maybe add this to your answer so people who have the same problem find it better.